Problem with greyed out action editor

Action editor all functions greyed out, can't make or edit any actions.

Any chance the armature was linked from another blend file ?

No it was made in this file

Your action has been pushed down to NLA.
Go to NLA Window, select the action and press Tab to make it editable in the action editor.
Press Tab again when finished (hovering NLA window).

